# How to communicate with the web using java

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications

I'm writing a program in Java and I need this program to enter a site, send it a query and collect its answers.

For example, I want my program to insert a string to search in Google and retrieve the first site that appears.

Can you please direct me to an api, library or jars that I can use for this end?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from Apache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URLConnection.  It's part of the JDK; no need for a library.  [Here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html) is an example on how to use it.